# How do I delete a Windows 8 recovery partition that won't delete through command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, recovery-partition

I need to delete that nasty recovery image partition which is taking up my space as I moved my windows and recovery drive to different hard disk

It won't delete (when I right click it says nothing besides "Help").

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEkTb.png]

I also tried deleting it via command prompt, nothing happens!

Comment: Have you tried using diskpart?

Comment: yes, in command prompt

Comment: Did you run the cmd as admin?

Comment: did it just now(yes) says can't run on current boot..

Comment: If it's really annoying, you could always move what you want to keep and DBAN it.

Comment: @meatspace Yes, I suggested below to boot a live CD and delete and extend etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately according to [this](http://www.winability.com/delete-protected-efi-disk-partition/):

> if you are trying to erase the system disk that hosts the C: drive
>   where Windows itself is installed and running, then even the powerful
>   DISKPART command can't work: Windows simply refuses to erase the drive
>   from which it is running.
>
> To erase such a disk, you need to physically remove it from the
>   computer, attach it to another computer as an external drive, and then
>   use DISKPART on that computer to erase the disk.

Comment: Although, you may be able to boot a live cd of Linux and remove it, worth a shot. (Try using 'gparted')

Comment: im NOT erasing C: drive... my recovery drive is Not windows host disk and its not efi partition

Comment: im trying to install liunux on disk where recovery drive is now, my windows are in different disk, but im still using my , main one

Comment: The partition your trying to delete is on the host drive that your c: partition is on so try and remove it via a Linux host.

Comment: would doing same thing from different disk do the deal?

Comment: If you mean a different environment then yes, this has nothing to do with disks. You could boot linux from a dead badger and still delete it regardless of what disk it is on.